# how to run a shell command in perl in backticks when command also has backticks

Tags: perl

example.

```
$output= `eval `environment` ; echo $Variable` ;
```

i want to execute this command

```
eval `environment` ; echo $Variable
```

in a perl script.

Comment: Smells like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). What is it that you *really* want to do?

Comment: Why you would like to call a shell script? You can use `ENV`module to get the environment variables.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> $output= `eval `environment` ; echo $Variable` ;
> ```

Use [the `qx//` form](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) from the "Quote-like Operators":

```
my $output = qx{eval `environment` ; echo $Variable};
```

But that still probably wouldn't do what you want, since `$Variable` would be already evaluated and interpolated by Perl. To fix that:

```
# single quotes:
my $command = q{eval `environment` ; echo $Variable};
# and then execute it:
my $output = qx{$command};
```

Alternatively, a little hack:

```
my $output = qx'eval `environment` ; echo $Variable';
```

When the `'` is used as the character to the quote-like operators, it inhibits the variable interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

You may use Backtiks "here documents" - see Backtics sub section in [`man perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) for details.  $ sign must be escaped if you want to avoid variable expansion by perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;  
use warnings;

my $output =  <<`END`;
eval `environment` ; echo \$Variable
END

print $output;
```